# Testing with UIAutomator android

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I am something new to **Testing** concept in android.

I am trying to test **Facebook login** with UIAutomator.

I have downloaded the **UIAutomator tool**

When I do `$ uiautomatorviewer` I get `Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer`

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to the directory where uiautomatorviewer.bat locate.
In Windows, it is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools